# Pam_mount on centos

Tags: build, mount, pam, centos7

So I'm trying to build pam_mount on my centos 7 machine, and it's not going all too well.

I ran `configure`, `make` and `make install` and it seems to be build and installed correctly:

```
# make install
Making install in config
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/config'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/config'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/etc/security'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pam_mount.conf.xml '/usr/etc/security'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/config'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/config'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/man/man5'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pam_mount.conf.5 '/usr/share/man/man5'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/man/man8'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 mount.crypt.8 mount.crypt_LUKS.8 mount.crypto_LUKS.8 pmvarrun.8 pmt-ehd.8 umount.crypt.8 umount.crypt_LUKS.8 umount.crypto_LUKS.8 pam_mount.8 '/usr/share/man/man8'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/doc'
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libcryptmount.la '/usr/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcryptmount.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/libcryptmount.so.0.0.0
libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libcryptmount.so.0.0.0 libcryptmount.so.0 || { rm -f libcryptmount.so.0 && ln -s libcryptmount.so.0.0.0 libcryptmount.so.0; }; })
libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libcryptmount.so.0.0.0 libcryptmount.so || { rm -f libcryptmount.so && ln -s libcryptmount.so.0.0.0 libcryptmount.so; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libcryptmount.lai /usr/lib/libcryptmount.la
libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/lib'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/sbin'
  /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c pmvarrun '/usr/sbin'
libtool: install: warning: `libcryptmount.la' has not been installed in `/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/pmvarrun /usr/sbin/pmvarrun
make  install-exec-hook
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p /sbin;
for i in umount.crypt mount.crypto_LUKS umount.crypto_LUKS mount.crypt_LUKS umount.crypt_LUKS; do \
    ln -s -f mount.crypt "/sbin/$i"; \
done;
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/include'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcryptmount.h '/usr/include'
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/lib/security'
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   pam_mount.la '/lib/security'
libtool: install: warning: relinking `pam_mount.la'
libtool: install: (cd /root/pam_mount-2.15/src; /bin/sh /root/pam_mount-2.15/libtool  --silent --tag CC --mode=relink gcc -Wall -Waggregate-return -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wformat=2 -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -g -O2 -module -avoid-version -o pam_mount.la -rpath /lib/security pam_mount_la-misc.lo pam_mount_la-mount.lo pam_mount_la-pam_mount.lo pam_mount_la-rdconf1.lo pam_mount_la-rdconf2.lo pam_mount_la-spawn.lo libcryptmount.la -lpam -L/lib64 -lHX -lmount -lpcre -lxml2 )
libtool: relink: warning: `/lib64/libHX.la' seems to be moved
libtool: relink: warning: library `/lib64/libHX.la' was moved.
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/pam_mount.soT /lib/security/pam_mount.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/pam_mount.lai /lib/security/pam_mount.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /lib/security
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /lib/security

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/sbin'
  /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c mount.crypt '/sbin'
libtool: install: warning: `libcryptmount.la' has not been installed in `/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/mount.crypt /sbin/mount.crypt
make  install-data-hook
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
rm -f /lib/security/pam_mount.la;
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15/src'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libcryptmount.pc '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
make  install-data-hook
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15'
/usr/bin/mkdir -p /usr/var/run/pam_mount;
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/pam_mount-2.15'
```

but when I try to validate the install, I get an error

```
# xmllint --nonet --noout --loaddtd --valid --path    /usr/share/xml/pam_mount/dtd/pam_mount.conf.xml.dtd /etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml
warning: failed to load external entity "/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml"
```

What went wrong? I really need to get pam_mount working on centos

Here's a link for pam_mount install doc: http://sourceforge.net/p/pam-mount/pam-mount/ci/master/tree/doc/install.txt#l48

EDIT

---

I found the pam_mount.conf.xml in /usr/etc/security but the validation wanted it to be in /etc/security.

I tried using the one config I found, but with no luck

Can anyone help me install pam_mount correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The RPM is now available from nux desktop repository

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=48818